# URL Generation for paperclip document based on version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am trying to implement file versioning in my application. I  have the following model in my application.

```
    class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
     versioned
     attr_accessible :name,:file,:attachable_type,:attachable_id
     belongs_to :user
     belongs_to :attachable , :polymorphic => true
     has_attached_file :file, :preserve_files => true
     Paperclip.interpolates :version do |attachment, style|  
      attachment.instance.version.to_s  
     end
    end
```

Paper clip uploads all documents to Amazon S3.The path is as follows.

```
    Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:version/:style/:filename'
```

If I use

```
    document.file.url
```

I am able to get the path to latest file. How to get the url path for a specific version of the file?
I tried passing version as a argument to the url method, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    document.file.url(:original, :version => 2)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what did you send up with?

Comment: I have used a document_version model to represent a version.